# SQS DLQ with Bucket S3 or Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have this situation:

On production environment, we don't have permission to list our DLQ messages for security issues, so we are looking for another way to work to get these DLQ messages, analyse it and send to processment or delete they.

Is it possible to make our SQS to save those messages in a bucket S3 instead DQL? If it's not, is there a way to build a lambda function to read those DLQ messagens and send to SQS or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make our SQS to save those messages in a bucket S3
> instead DQL?

Not automatically. You would need to write a Lambda function to do that.

> If it's not, is there a way to build a lambda function to read those
> DLQ messagens and send to SQS or delete it?

Yes of course AWS Lambda can do this.

Comment: That's good to know, do you have any tutorial on how to do this? I've already search and didn't find anything in particular.

Comment: You would just configure the DLQ as the source for a Lambda function. It's just another SQS queue, you can treat it like any other SQS queue. Then have the Lambda function use the AWS SDK to write to S3 or delete the message from SQS or whatever you want it to do.

Comment: Create an AWS Lambda function that is triggered from the Dead Letter Queue. The function should look at the message passed via the `event` parameter and create an object in Amazon S3 with that message.